# How to check dependency of one column to another in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
 import pandas as pd

 df=pd.DataFrame([[1,11,'a'],[1,12,'a'],[1,11,'a'],[1,12,'a'],[1,7,'a'],
                [1,12,'a']])
 df.columns=['id','code','name']

 df

    id  code name
0   1    11    a
1   1    12    a
2   1    11    a
3   1    12    a
4   1     7    a
5   1    12    a
```

As shown in the above dataframe, the value of column "id" is directly related to the value of column "name". If I have say, a million records, how can I know that a column is totally dependent on other column in a dataframe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If they are totally dependent, then their factorizations will be the same

```
(df.id.factorize()[0] == df.name.factorize()[0]).all()

True
```

Comment: This is nice! This actually detects a 1:1 relationship between the columns. But how about a 1:N relationship? How to go from `iff id=x then name=y` to `if id=x then name=y` Is there some separate question for that?